# how to write an if statement in python comparing time to a value

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to write a simple code in python to turn on a led light during certain hours of the day, then turn it off for the rest of the time. I tried to indicate the time frames in the if statement but everytime I run this code, only the "else" portion of the if statement works. Am I not allowed to compare my time format of HHMM to a flat value of 0745? If not how can I get the led to stay on from midnight to 7:45 in the morning? Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)
print (time.strftime("%H%M"))

while True:
    if time.strftime("%H%M") <= 0745:
        GPIO.output(3,1)
    else:
        GPIO.output(3,0)
```

Comment: You don't need to write on/off to the LED constantly. You could use a boolean to ensure that you only write a high once `if not is_on` and a low `if is_on`

Comment: `0745` is an octal integer literal (for `485` in decimal), which you're comparing to a string. I guess you meant `'0745'`, a string.

Comment: `time.strftime("%H%M")` is a `str`, 0745 is an `int`. make them the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use datetime.

```
import datetime
while True:
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    morning = time.replace(hour=7, minute=45, second=0, microsecond=0)
    if time <= morning:
        print("turn on")
    else:
        print("turn off")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html) module that provides data types to work with dates and times.

You could write the code from your question like this:

```py
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now() <= datetime.datetime.combine(
      datetime.date.today(),
      datetime.time(7, 45)
    ):
        GPIO.output(3,1)
    else:
        GPIO.output(3,0)
```

However, this still has the problem that the program will constantly spin in the while loop and suck up as much CPU cycles as it can get.

You could do something like this instead:

```
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)

schedule = [
    (datetime.time(0, 0), 0),
    (datetime.time(7, 45), 1),
    (datetime.time(18, 0), 0)
    ]

def switchLight():
    """
    Switch the light to the proper state according to the schedule.
    Return the next time the light needs to be switched.
    """
    today = datetime.date.today()
    schedule_index = 0
    while schedule_index < len(schedule) and \
          datetime.datetime.now() > datetime.datetime.combine(today, schedule[schedule_index][0]):
        schedule_index += 1
    GPIO.output(3, schedule[schedule_index][1])

    # calculate next switching time
    schedule_index += 1
    if schedule_index == len(schedule):
        schedule_index = 0
        today = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return datetime.datetime.combine(today, schedule[schedule_index][0])

while True:
    next_time = switchLight()
    time.sleep((next_time - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds + 1)
```